Spring websocket connection closed by spring cloud gateway after 30 seconds
My application is a microservice application. I am using spring web sockets to send notifications to the front end. In my application, I have a gateway service to route the HTTP requests to the relevant service which uses Spring Cloud Gateway Global filter, and I am using same Spring Cloud Gateway to route the web socket connection to the relevant microservice. But Spring Cloud Gateway closed my web socket connection after 30 seconds. Hence I was unable to use the web socket. How to increase or remove this timeout?
To route the WebSocket connection to the relevant service I have used the following routes.
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway.routes:
      - id: websocket_route
        uri: wss://websocket-service-svc/**
        predicates:
          - Path=/api/v1/websocket-service/ws-websocket

Is there any way to remove the time-out configuration or increase the timeout time?

The Websocker Routing Filter in the Spring Cloud Gateway docs (see link) shows the following note:

If you use SockJS as a fallback over normal HTTP, you should configure a normal HTTP route as well as the websocket Route.

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      # SockJS route
      - id: websocket_sockjs_route
        uri: http://localhost:3001
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/info/**
      # Normal Websocket route
      - id: websocket_route
        uri: ws://localhost:3001
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/**

I believe this could be applicable to your case?
